# access xampp server online without getting hacked

Tags: php, html, laravel, xampp

hi im working with xampp and laravel 8
the software author don't want the server to be online but he want to have it as localhost server
and also he want to access the server from outside

```
online xampp server
```

before tow years i was working in project as localhost and i opened port with my static ip so i access the project online ..
but the problem was thats i get hacked encrypt all files after i turned of the firewall .. and im afraid to have the same problem again ..

```
xampp
```

so what is the safest way to make xampp server can access online ..
thanks

Comment: Don't turn off your whole firewall!! use port forwarding on your router to open only the port to the webserver. And use authentication so not everyone can access the site without a password. Make sure the web and database users configured on your site don't have too many privileges - e.g. no write permissions to the filesystem, no excessive database rights, etc. Make sure the code isn't vulnerable to SQL injection or XSS, etc. Basically all the same things you'd do if the site was hosted on a server. You've made it public, so you need to take all security precautions. It's a broad topic.

Comment: Well XAMPP is a local dev environment, you should not make it available online. If you want to host an application locally, you should put it in a virtual machine instead (or use a docker container)

Comment: And yes using a VM or container is a good idea too, it should reduce the damage if anything does get hacked.